# Cannot run React app / react-router-dom / bootstrap

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm a complete newbie trying to learn react. I messed up something and i could not run the app. It always returned gigantic amount of vulnerabilities or just things I have no idea what they are. Please forgive me if I'm too ambiguous, I have not technical understanding of how to run these things

This is what I get when i run npm start

```
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
  postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
  postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
  postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
  postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
  postcss-normalize-url  1.1.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
  postcss-ordered-values  <=4.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
  postcss-overflow-shorthand  <=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  <=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  <=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  <=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-reduce-initial  <=4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  <=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-safe-parser  <=4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-safe-parser
  postcss-selector-matches  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  postcss-unique-selectors  <=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  stylehacks  <=4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks


request  *
Severity: moderate
Server-Side Request Forgery in Request - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p8p7-x288-28g6
Depends on vulnerable versions of tough-cookie
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/request
  request-promise-core  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of request
  node_modules/request-promise-core
    request-promise-native  >=1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of request
    Depends on vulnerable versions of request-promise-core
    Depends on vulnerable versions of tough-cookie
    node_modules/request-promise-native

semver  6.0.0 - 6.3.0
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@5.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/semver

shell-quote  <=1.7.2
Severity: critical
Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in a Command in Shell-quote - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g4rg-993r-mgx7
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@5.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/shell-quote

tough-cookie  <4.1.3
Severity: moderate
tough-cookie Prototype Pollution vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-72xf-g2v4-qvf3
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tough-cookie

119 vulnerabilities (1 low, 97 moderate, 17 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
PS C:\Users\PC\test> npm list react-router-dom
test@0.1.0 C:\Users\PC\test
└── (empty)

PS C:\Users\PC\test> npm list boostrap 
test@0.1.0 C:\Users\PC\test
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\PC\test\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I have installed react-router-dom before, but I reinstalled it when i created this app. It did not work for some reason, and I get lots of vulnerabilities. I tried `npm audit fix --force` but it did not work, and since then everytime I tried to run react-router-dom or just starting the react app it all failed

C:\Users\PC>npm list react-router-dom
PC@ C:\Users\PC
`-- react-router-dom@6.21.3
This is what I get when I run in my terminal on the computer

PS C:\Users\PC\test> npm list react-router-dom
test@0.1.0 C:\Users\PC\test
└── (empty)
But this is what I get when I run in the terminal in VSCODE in the react app

Please help me, I have been stuck here for hours and I felt like I have done irreversible damage to my laptop

I tried running npm audit fix --force but only created more vulnerabilities